# Apache rewrite with GET parameters not working

Tags: regex, apache, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a url: [www.example.com/products.php?category=category](http://www.example.com/products.php?category=category)
that I want to rewrite to [www.example.com/products/category](http://www.example.com/products/category)

(the category can be either meats, condiments or smokers depending on which products user wants to see)

I've used some rewrite rules that I've seen in stack overflow and other sources, but no luck.

The closest I've been is the page loading, but the category parameter is returned null instead of with the value.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)$ products.php?category=$1 [L,QSA]
```

will load the page [www.example.com/products/meats](http://www.example.com/products/meats), but the server only receives null from the category query.

Tried this as well:

```
# Check if the request is for /products.php with a category query parameter 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/products\.php$ 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^category=meats$ 
# If the conditions are met, rewrite to /products/<category> with the query string 
RewriteRule ^products\.php$ /products/%1 [L,QSA]
```

Just get a 404 error for both pages

Comment: Tried this as well:

# Check if the request is for /products.php with a category query parameter
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/products\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^category=meats$

# If the conditions are met, rewrite to /products/<category> with the query string
RewriteRule ^products\.php$ /products/%1 [L,QSA]

Just get a 404 error for both pages

Comment: shouldn't be rather `RewriteRule ^products\.php\?category=([^&]+)$ products/$1` ?

Comment: What does "*but the server only receives null from the category query*" mean?  Your first rewrite rule looks correct, and if the page loads it suggests it works.  So what is your PHP doing?  Your 2nd example is going the wrong way, redirecting from your current URL format to URLs which don't exist. Also `%1` is used to match the first back-reference in `RewriteCond`, but you don't have any here. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: It's **not very clear** for me as your first *RewriteRule* is to handle URLs such as `/products/my-category` with a PHP script called `products.php`. Is it the case? Or have you got old published URLs pointing to `/products.php?category=my-category` and you would like to rewrite them to nice clean URLs for, let's say, a new website running behind with another technology? Is your *Apache* virtual host acting as a reverse proxy?

Comment: @PatrickJanser The first sentence of the question explains the current situation and the requirement.  It seems like the classic "pretty URLs" requirement.

Answer (score 0):

As @DontPanic said, your first *RewriteRule* is correct. I had a go on
my *Apache* installation and it works fine with the following config.

##### Content of `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^products/([^/]+)$ products.php?category=$1 [L,QSA]
```

By the way, if you add the optional leading slash before `products` you
get the same behaviour:

```
RewriteRule ^/?products/([^/]+)$ products.php?category=$1 [L,QSA]
```

##### Content of `products.php`

```php
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "\n";

print '$_GET = ' . var_export($_GET, true) . ";\n";
```

This is what my browser outputs for `http://rewrites.local/products/smoky-stuff` :

```
/products.php
$_GET = array (
  'category' => 'smoky-stuff',
);
```

A few ideas about the 404 error:

- Did you verify that
  [*mod_rewrite*](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html)
  is enabled on your server?
- How is [*AllowOverride*](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#allowoverride)
  set for this web site (*VirtualHost*)?
  Is
  [*FileInfo*](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/overrides.html#override-fileinfo)
  allowed to be overridden?
  It actually gives you the possibility to do
  *RewriteRules* in the `.htaccess` file, so you need to have
  something like this :

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80> 
      DocumentRoot "/var/www/rewrites.local"
      ServerName rewrites.local
      <Directory "/var/www/rewrites.local">
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
      </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
  ```

  Or at least *FileInfo* allowed :

  ```
  AllowOverride FileInfo
  ```